# How to increase ALB metric retention time for AWS cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

After combing through the docs and looking for other sources, I was only able to find documentation on logging and log retention. Is there any way to increase the retention time for ec2/ALB metrics such as response time, unique connections, etc, or is metric retention time standard and unchangeable?

I've looked for other documentation for this but haven't been able to find any as of yet. Log groups don't seem to encapsulate metrics, so that's a no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change CloudWatch metrics retention. If you want to keep it for longer than 15 months, you'll have to come up with your own solution to export the metrics elsewhere.

> The longest period that metrics are stored in CloudWatch is 15 months. If you want to store metrics data beyond a 15-month period, you must query the metrics data, before CloudWatch performs aggregation on your metrics, and store it in an alternate repository, such as Amazon DynamoDB, Amazon S3, or Amazon RDS.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/writing-and-archiving-custom-metrics-using-amazon-cloudwatch-and-aws-tools-for-powershell/